# Endebted v. indebted: is there a difference in meaning?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, meaning-in-context, british-english

I was recently told by a senior academic that I ought to replace the word *indebted* with *endebted* in an essay during which I suggest one text alludes to another.

I have searched the web (no help) and looked in 1991's Compact OED (the entry for *endebt* directs readers to  *indebt*).

Comment: I've never heard/seen _endebted_, only _indebted_. Admittedly, my exposure is principally to AmE, so I suppose it _could_ exist in BrE,  given that you found it in Oxford.

Comment: I trust your "senior academic" doesn't claim to be highly-qualified in *English*. The archaic/obsolete spelling cited above [never had any currency](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+am+endebted%2CI+am+indebted&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20am%20endebted%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20am%20indebted%3B%2Cc0), and only a complete idiot would suppose it had some special meaning different to the conventional spelling.

Comment: BTW, is there a resurgence of the forgotten spelling *endebted*, even more so in BrE? Also, is *indebted* being replaced by another term these days?

Comment: "Arganda del Rey is one of the most **endebted** councils of Spain, owing over €100m, mainly owing to money wasted on secret projects from the previous Partido Popular-led council. " https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arganda_del_Rey (emphasis mine) (Could be a translation issue.)

Comment: "I am **endebted** to Jan Dizard, Harold Raush, and Cathy Portuges for numerous discussions of the issues considered in this chapter." (emphasis mine) https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0065240708600397#!

Comment: "53 years ago...introduction of artificial heart assist by Dr Michael DeBakey made history! Forever **endebted** to trailblazers & pioneers in Medicine.   (22 Apr 2018) (emphasis mine) https://twitter.com/WilliamZoghbi/status/988099604913717251

Comment: @JeffZeitlin You didn't google it, obviously.

Comment: "BOBBY AND BILL - EP48 - Endebted for life"

Comment: Indebted is so rare in British usage that I had never heard of it before today. Best avoided.

Comment: So it seems as though there's a clear difference in US versus UK usage?

Comment: Another pair that shows up in both forms with some frequency: _embed_ and _imbed_. These are simply variant spellings; I don't think that they differ at all in meaning.

Comment: I see above that on June 14 I wrote "Indebted is so rare in British usage that I had never heard of it before today.". Of course I meant to write "Endebted". "Indebted" is the normal word.

Answer (score -1):

*Endebted* is the obsolete form of *indebted*.

Comment: According to some dictionaries. But is it? No.